# Option in drop down list calculation

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string IsChauffeurUsed = "Yes";
    totalValue += IsChauffeurUsed.Equals("Yes", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? 80 : 0;
    Label8.Text = totalValue.ToString();
```

The above line of code make the system add 80 add after calculate

```
 int totalValue = 0;
    totalValue = int.Parse(Session["price"].ToString()) * int.Parse(Session["day"].ToString());
```

How to make it only add 80 if ONLY user select "yes" in drop down list. I store the selection in session

```
Session["IsChauffeurUsed"] = DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string IsChauffeurUsed = Session["IsChauffeurUsed"].ToString();
totalValue += IsChauffeurUsed.Equals("Yes", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ? 80 : 0;
```

This depends on the value being set to "Yes" in the Dropdown.

Comment: Thnk you. You such a saver of d day :)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I think would be:

```
string IsChauffeurUsed = CB.SelectedItem.ToString();
if (IsChauffeurUsed == "Yes")
{
  //Do condition calculations here
}
```

Might not be fancy, but I'm pretty sure it works.